# Visual Studio rebase v git rebase

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

We are finding that we get different results when we do a git rebase as opposed to a Visual Studio (2019, Enterprise) rebase. Note that we are new to git in general

We have a branch called (for example) SomeFeature, then we have people working on it who have their own branches:

- SomeFeature_mike
- SomeFeature_tony

Mike works off SomeFeature_mike, makes changes, does a pull request and gets his work into SomeFeature, tony now wants to rebase off of SomeFeature so that he gets Mike's changes

Using Visual Studio we sometimes get merge errors, but we're not sure why. If instead we do this

```
git checkout SomeFeature_tony
git rebase origin/SomeFeature
```

Then it appears to work

The suspicion is that after a rebase and a sync we haven't been force pushing the SomeFeature_tony branch, however that doesn't answer the core question, why is Visual Studio doing something different to git?

Comment: I can confirm that your syntax for rebasing via the command line is correct.  The advice I give people is to just stick with the command line, and avoid Git GUIs :)

Answer (score 1):

In my cognition,I don't think it has different between Visual Studio 'rebase' option and 'git rebase'.But 'merge' is different from 'rebase'.

When you merge SomeFeature_tony to SomeFeature , it will combine SomeFeature branch with your current commit in SomeFeature_tony and form a new commit.Just like following pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK5PD.png)

When you rebase,it will make commits of SomeFeature_tony behind SomeFeature. Just like following pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk9e2.png)

When you merge one branch into another, file changes from commits in one branch can conflict with the changes the other.You can resolve it just like you resolve [merge conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) in Visual Studio.Also you can  do a 'git add' to stage the merged changes, then continue the rebase with 'git rebase --continue'.

Hope this help and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a "git rebase" before doing a "git merge" is not exactly like doing directly a "git merge".  Specially if you merge with fast forward (this will keep your merge [master] branch clean and straight :) ).

```
a-b-c-d [master]
  \x-y-z [feature]
```

direct merge

```
a-b-c-d--m   [master]
  \x-y-z/    [feature]
```

rebase + merge

```
1) rebase
    a-b-c-d [master]
           \x-y-z [feature]
2) merge
    a-b-c-d-x-y-z [master & feature]
```

The way merge constraint are seen in "direct merge" and "rebase + merge" are a bit different (even if final state is/'should be' identical). 
In one case you apply to common point all modification increments from both side and check conflict.
In the other case you move the modification increments to a new position.

I would recommend this last solution as it allow after rebase to test as it will be after merging.

I suggest you to read https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

So even with your IDE rebase before merging to get similar result as your cmd line. Note that there might be plenty of option set by your IDE that could influence the git commands.